# How to remove this unrelated block of code, that checks child's availability in the container

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

This is my code on button click. It adds myView to the container. And takes care of fact that all previous instances get removed before adding again. I wanna know, if there is some better way of making this "check" ? I especially wanna have some way to remove the 1s 7 lines of this code ( within comments). It seems like an unrelated block of code in the normal code-flow.

```
function button_CLICK(e:Event)
{
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
            if ( myView!= null)
            {
                if ( contains(myView))
                {
                    removeChild(myView) ;
                }
            }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            myView = new myView("hello")
            addChild(myView);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would depend on what the object `myView` consists of.  if, for example, it has its own event listeners you would want to use the condition check to clean up the object before disposing of it so there are no memory leaks.

```
function button_CLICK(e:Event):void
{
    if (myView && contains(myView))
    {
        //clean up myView

        removeChild(myView);
    }

    myView = new myView("hello");
    addChild(myView);
}
```

however, if `myView` is a simple display object that doesn't contain any leakable references or event listeners than you could simply reassign the variable to overwrite the previous.

keep in mind that `addChild()` places the added display object on top above all others.  but regardless if that's something you'd like to avoid or not, i believe it would be better to assign a default or empty view once instead of `addChild(myView)` each time the button is clicked.

```
function button_CLICK(e:Event):void
{
    myView = new myView("hello");
}
```

i assume your code is for for demonstration because `new myView("hello")` is going to always be the same object?  unless perhaps this object relies on dates or timers to make instances different from previous constructs.

Comment: Be careful with the contains(..) function, it checks recursively. The safest way would be "if (myView && myView.parent == this)"

Answer (score 0):

The checking code you have could create a memory leak as you don't null the previous myView before creating a new instance. NB. It's good practice to begin the name of your classes with an uppercase letter.

Your code also seems to allow for the button_CLICK method to be called when myView has been added. Perhaps consider hiding the button when the view has been added.

You could just have one instance of the MyView Class instantiated. Then rather than having to null and create a new instance each time, just add the same one and add an init function that will accept the initialising parameters. e.g.

```
var myView = new MyView();

function button_CLICK(e:Event)
{
if ( contains(myView))
{
removeChild(myView) ;
}
}
myView.init("hello");
addChild(myView);

}
```

Comment: Not setting a reference to null will not cause memory leaks if it's immediately overwritten by another value. Only keeping the reference will.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have much of an option, based on the (IMO) flawed implementation of DisplayObjectContainer. If you're feeling feisty, you can "fix" removeChild to see if the child is there before calling the super method, rather than simply throwing an error, as Adobe thought was the appropriate solution.

Your code above will still run, but it will be in the removeChild override.

Answer (score 0):

Your commented bloc of code is necessary only  for the first call to `button_CLICK` (you sould rename this method : `buttonClick`).
After the firts call, this bloc of code is unnecessary.
In order to remove this code `myView` should be not `null`, and an instance of `MyView` should be added on the display list.

```
var myView : MyView;

function init(){
   myView = new MyView("FAKE");
   myView.visible = false;
   addChild(myView);
   addEventListener("click",click);
}

function click(e:MouseEvent):void{
   removeChild(myView);
   myView = new Child("REAL");
   addChild(myView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(myView != null)
    myView.parent && myView.parent.removeChild(myView);
```